# Remove OBJECT with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I remove an object with jquery.

```
$('.Line1').each(function (i, obj) {
      if (obj.id != myVariable) {

      }

});
```

See that I can't remove this object with `$( ".hello" ).remove();` because it is an object. How can I do it with the code from above?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try making object null explicitly? ```obj=null```

Comment: What do you mean by remove? Are you asking to remove a property from an object? Which object? Usually in JS, you can use `delete obj.id` to delete the id property from an obj.

Comment: I want to delete it but dw I found it out.
It is $(obj).remove();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$('.Line1').each(function (i, obj) {
      if (obj.id != myVariable) {
          $(obj).remove();
      } 
});
```

When you loop through a jQuery object using each, you get the elements themselves, not each element wrapped in a jQuery object. You need to wrap each element in a jQuery object to use the remove method:

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `.each()` you can grab the current element with `$(this)`. Then you can do something like:

```
$(".elements").each(function() {
    if("some-statement" == "true") {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

This will remove it from the DOM. Alternatively you can hide it using `.hide()`.